# Matlab parallel computing throws error for bigger matrices : Index must not exceed 0

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, parallel-processing, compiler-errors

I am a newbie in parallel computing.

I am doing some calculation to generate a 4D data. It worked fined while calculating a 4D matrix of small size(for e.g. 2 × 3 × 4 × 100). But it then threw an error when the matrix sized was increased to  5 × 101 × 1001 × 101.

Below is my minimal code script.
'A' is the 4D matrix to be generated. The calculations necessary are done by my function 'bem4DParallel'.

So, at the innermost loop, a 1D array A_L is calculated. It is then stored in the 2D matrix A_K. This is done parallelly for different values of k.
Then it is stored in 3D matrix A_J and then finally in the 4D matrix A.

Computations for input_3 are parallelized. I didn't parallelize the innermost loop because to there is a dependency of the variable. That is, calculation of A_L(l) in the innermost loop required the value of A_L(l-1). That's why I am passing the whole A_L array in the function while calculating.

```
% script name: main4DParallel.m
% inputs
input_1 = 0:5:20;
input_2 = 0:100;
input_3 = 500:1500;
input_4 = 0:0.01:2;
% 4D matrix to be calculated
A = zeros( length(input_1), length(input_2), length(input_3), length(input_4) ); 
for i = 1:length(input_1)
    
    arg_1 = input_1(i);
    A_J = zeros(length(input_2), length(input_3), length(input_4));
    
        for j = 1:length(input_2)
            
             arg_2 = input_2(j);
             A_K = zeros(length(input_3), length(input_4));
                     
             % parallel computing
             parfor k = 1:length(input_3)
                 
                 arg_3 = input_3(k);
                 A_L = zeros(1,length(input_4));
                 
                 for l = 1:length(input_4)                                                    
                     a = bem4DParallel(arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, input_4(l), A_L, l); 
                     A_L(l) = a; 
                 end
                     
                 A_K(k,:) = A_L;
                                         
             end
             A_J(j,:,:) = A_K;
                     
        end
        
        A(i,:,:,:) = A_J;
        
end
```

The script runs for some time(about 12 hours) and then gives the following error:
[image]

'main4DParallel' is the name of this script. And line 103 corresponds to the line where we have **parfor k = 1:length(input_3)**

After stopping, the values of the looping variables in the workspace are:
i = 1, j = 3. And there exists no k and l values.

Matrices:
A_L does not exist
2D matrix 'A_K' exist. And also data are present upto a row of  24. (Is it something to do with number of matlab workers?)
3D Matrix 'A_J' exist and contains value upto
A_J(2,:,:)
Make sense, because after stopping, j is at a value of 3
4D matrix A is completely empty.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error occurs inside `bem4DParallel`? If so, we need to see that code. I suggest you read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. Nobody is going to run code for 12 hours to reproduce your problem, you will need to reduce the code size and the amount of computations for us to help you. Likely, once you work on that, you will find the issue by yourself. Reducing code to its essence is a wonderful way of finding bugs.